# minimalmodbus : Wrong Message being sent over Serial

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

So i want to send this code : `01 00 14 00 58` over ModBus RTU utilizing minimalmodbus to my VIRTUAL COM Port (COM2).

So i do get the "code" but i also get other bytes before and after the code and i can seem to know where they come from and how i can resolve it.

[Terminal Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icijI.png)

I did try to use another libary called pymodbus but i got the same result

**PythonCode :**

```
import serial
import minimalmodbus as mrtu
mrtu.BYTEORDER_BIG = 1
insmrt = mrtu.Instrument('COM2',1 ,mrtu.MODE_RTU,close_port_after_each_call= False,debug=True)
insmrt.precalculate_read_size= False
insmrt.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction= True
insmrt.serial.baudrate = 38400
insmrt.serial.bytesize = 8
insmrt.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
insmrt.serial.stopbits  =1
insmrt.serial.timeout = 5
insmrt.handle_local_echo = None
def inscommmand():

    #insmrt.write_string = "$0100140058"
    insmrt.write_registers(0,[0x01,0x14,0x58])
while 1:
    try:
         inscommmand()
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Hello Kevin, welcome to SO. I don't think you have understood how Modbus works. When you call `write_registers()` minimalModbus creates a Modbus frame based on the registers and values you want to write. But it also needs to include other information to complete the protocol: the slave you are addressing and the checksum. Those are the *other bytes* you see. You should think exactly what you mean when you say *I want to send this code...* and ask yourself this question instead: what values do I want to write and in which register numbers should they end up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you are trying to do or what you mean exactly by *send this code by Modbus* but I'm afraid what the library (minimalModbus) is doing is exactly what it is supposed to.

If you call:

```
insmrt.write_registers(0,[0x01,0x14,0x58])
```

The library will build the following Modbus frame:

```
01 10 0000 0003 06 0001 0014 0058 9ABE
```

This is what each value on this frame means:

`01`: The Slave Address (default is address 1)

`10`: The Function Code 16 (Write Multiple Holding Registers, 16 = 10 hex)

`0000`: The address of the first register (0000 hex = 0, +40001 offset = register #40001).

`0003`: Number of registers to write since you are giving a 3-element list

`06`: Number of data bytes that follow (3 registers x 2 bytes each = 6 bytes).

`0001`: Value to write to register 40001

`0014`: Value to write to register 40002

`0058`: Value to write to register 40003

`9ABE`: The [CRC](https://crccalc.com/?crc=01100000000306000100140058&method=CRC-16/MODBUS&datatype=hex&outtype=0) (Cyclic Redundancy Check) for error checking.

The sequence `01 00 14 00 58` is not a valid Modbus frame because there is no function code `00`(only values from 1 to 6, 15, and 16 are allowed).

Maybe what you want is just to send that sequence over the serial port? Otherwise, you should think about where those values are coming from.

Comment: Okay , that does make sense
But let me explain why i think that i have to send it over through Modbus RTU.
So i did try to send it over "RealTerm" to the Device but it didn't work with the sequence i posted here , then i tried sending it through DCON Utilities and selected Modbus RTU and tried sending the exact sequence to the device and it worked

Comment: by DCON you mean with [this](https://www.icpdas.com/en/product/guide+Software+Utility_Driver+DCON__Utility__Pro)? I'm not familiar with that, if you explain how you enter the command there I might be able to understand how it works...

Comment: Yes exactly i used that software to send modbus commands to my device.
But you were right i was not sending Modbus sequences at all.
So i tried sending the same Sequence over Coolterm as a Hex and it worked
So it definitely wasn't Modbus related.

Comment: glad to hear. Good luck with your projects.